# Default boolean to something that isn't falsey in Django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm working in a Django template and I want to check the value of a boolean and print 'bold' if it's True, and 'plain' if it's False. If the value is blank or not defined, I want to treat it as if it is True. Here's what I'm currently using:

```
{{ something.boolean_val|yesno:"bold,plain,bold" }}
```

However, when `something.boolean` isn't defined, it's treating it as False, not None. I tried adding a `|default_if_none` filter, but that did nothing. When I tried `|default`, it changed False values as well.

Delving deeper into the docs, it seems that an undefined variable is set to `''` by default, which gets treated as False. I only want to treat an undefined variable as True (None would also be fine) in this particular situation, so I don't want to fiddle with `TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID`.

Is there a way to make this treat an undefined variable as True? Alternatively, is there a way I could distinguish `''` from False?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see it as a filter but in the template language logic you can use '==' which equates to '===' or 'is' in python and does not match None or '' to False the way that using 'not' does.

```
{% if something.boolean_val == False %}plain{% else %}bold{% endif %}
```

Comment: I'd fiddled around a bit with `if`s, but I must not have struck this particular setup. Didn't realize `==` equated to `===`, that's probably why. Anyway, this seems to be working. Thanks!